# Automapper 8.0+ all datetime to utc

Tags: c#, automapper

I would like to map all properties from datetime unspecified kind to UTC kind by just adding kind to datetime for mappings for all properties for Automapper 8.0, i found some maybe working solutions, but they are for older versions of Automapper that use ResolveUsing instead of MapFrom().
How to achieve that?

```
cfg.ForAllPropertyMaps(map => map.TypeMap.SourceType is IDbType && (map.SourceType == typeof(DateTime?) || map.SourceType == typeof(DateTime)), (map, expression) => { expression.ResolveUsing(o => { return #DO_WHATEVER_YOU_NEED# }); });
```

I want to map only all entities and Datetimes from server-> client to have Utc Kind added, above code is from github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1650

Comment: Simply use `MapFrom()`, see https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#resolveusing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ConvertUsing()` for a `CreateMap()` entry for the `DateTime` type. The code might look like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<DateTime, DateTime>().ConvertUsing((s, d) => {
    return DateTime.SpecifyKind(s, DateTimeKind.Utc);
});
```

Check the following example code:

```
class TestDTO {
    public DateTime SomeProp {get; set;}
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<TestDTO, TestDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<DateTime, DateTime>().ConvertUsing((s, d) => {
                return DateTime.SpecifyKind(s, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            });
        });
        TestDTO dto = new TestDTO {
            SomeProp = DateTime.Today
        };
        var mapper = new Mapper(config);
        DateTime now = dto.SomeProp;
        Console.WriteLine($"{now} - {now.Kind}");
        TestDTO changed = mapper.Map<TestDTO>(dto);
        DateTime nowWithKind = changed.SomeProp;
        Console.WriteLine($"{nowWithKind} - {nowWithKind.Kind}");            
    }  
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
6/16/2020 12:00:00 AM - Local
6/16/2020 12:00:00 AM - Utc
```

Comment: Can it be done for all properties instead of single DTOs?

Comment: @DankX1 Most likely, since there are helper methods like `ForAllMaps()` and such, but this depends on your actual configuration you are using. Or do you not use `CreateMap()`?

Comment: @DankX1 Then what is the problem? You define the mapping for `DateTime` -> `DateTime` as seen and the `DateTime` "kind" gets changed.

Comment: Oh ok great, will it work for both nullables and not datetimes? I need another mapping DateTime?, DateTime?

Comment: @DankX1 It does work for `DateTime?` as well. If it doesn't then you can add a `CreateMap<DateTime?, DateTime?>()` by yourself.